# Gpu to interface with an arm cpu

Tags: integrated-circuit, embedded, arm, cpu, gpu

I am building an embedded gaming system to... well to play games. I looked up to the gameboy advance cpu manual and saw that it had some sort of gpu. Where can I find a gpu to use with an arm cpu? I need it on a chip, I don't want to stick a whole gpu inside my device. What is the term for those?

Comment: Do those even exist nowadays short of the GPU you  might find on an Nvidia or Radeon card? They are mostly bundled with the processor in a system-on-chip now (like in a smartphone). Judging from your question, this project sounds beyond your ability for the time being. The other issue is "ARM CPU" is very vague and most will not have the proper pins to have interface with a GPU chip even if you had one. Is there even a lower-end bus that's not PCIE that would work with a GPU? A parallel bus maybe? I somehow doubt you'll find a parallel GPU chip though. No commercial customer I can think of.

Comment: Which embedded system? Which CPU? What interfaces does it have? There are solutions from an SPI Display controller to PCIe x16 full fledged GPU.

Comment: Do you want something with gameboy-style graphics, or something modern?

Comment: All of Nintendo's consoles had completely custom GPUs (that used to be *the* secret sauce for gaming systems). Nowadays, might I suggest using an FPGA to make one? There are some LCD controllers that have built-in GPU capabilities (e.g. 4D Systems) but I think they are just using a separate CPU to process the graphics, which is something you can do, too.

Comment: Many home-made game systems have success just by using the CPU as a GPU. They can run 2D games and even simple 3D. Remember that Doom ran on computers slower than a Gameboy.

Comment: So, what I understand from those is that if I do not care about the speed, I may use the CPU itself as the GPU. I had a thought of using an AVR microcontroller for the gpu. Is it possible? I know I may need to interface with an external ram.

Comment: Why pick one of slowest low end MCUs still manufactured? Particularly if you wish to use it for calculation-intense graphics? Why would you need external RAM? Sorry, but none of this makes any sense - you are going to need actual engineers for this project.

Comment: @Lundin Disagree, this can be done as a hobby project.

Comment: @JamesB.Reese You want a fast CPU as a GPU. Maybe something from the STM32 series. (I don't know specifics)

Comment: Or, if you want to spend a lot of time, an FPGA could be fun.

Comment: @user253751 Maybe so, if the hobbyist can tell the difference between a GPU and an AVR, or realize why a GPU is there in the first place.

Comment: People have made hardware emulators on FPGAs. That should tell you something. FPGAs are a different best than MCUs though but luckily you can get some on modules (not cheap, but at least buyable if you have a job) now so you don't have to deal with all the hardware complexity of implementing one.

Comment: @Lundin I know it won't be fast enough for my application, but that was just a thought. I would need extra ram only if I connect an AVR as the GPU as most of them don't have the ram to even store a whole frame. No, I don't think I would need engineers as this is a hobby project. I know the difference between a GPU and an AVR, that was the thought for if I couldn't find a suitable FPGA or a GPU for the job.

Comment: @JamesB.Reese Any mid-range ARM or similar 32 bitter will come with many Mb of on-board RAM. Unless you are looking to do some very high res, high color stuff, it will be more than enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, GPUs are mostly proprietary.

The Gameboy Advance - and most of Nintendo's consoles - used a completely custom GPU. Only Nintendo had it. You can't buy one.

The **good news** is that 2D graphics aren't too challenging.

Here are your options - in increasing order of computational power:

- Get a custom chip with a GPU built into it. Costs $X,XXX,XXX to set up. Not really an option. You don't have to know chip design - companies will do this for you - if you pay them a few million dollars.
- Use the main CPU to do all graphics. Even an overclocked AVR (yup, seriously) can process and render 2D games like Tetris and Mario, as in the [Uzebox](http://belogic.com/uzebox/howitsmade.htm). This is the ultimate low-part-count solution, and it's very *interesting*, but I suppose you want something more powerful.

  On the Uzebox, there is no extra video or sound hardware. There is just a DAC. The main CPU has to output the current pixel colour and sound level to the DAC, constantly, over and over. Apparently you get 6 clock cycles per pixel. Fun!

  Actually I lied - it has an extra chip to convert the pixel colours into NTSC video. But if you were using VGA, you could delete that chip.
- Do that, but with a faster CPU.

  I read that the STM32 line of ARM microcontrollers goes all the way up to 480MHz now. You could have a lot more clock cycles per pixel, and do more stuff per clock cycle.
- Use a separate CPU for graphics.

  You could make it run custom code that only does graphics, written in assembly with careful timing. Then your main CPU doesn't need to worry about squeezing the game logic into the spare clock cycles between pixels.

  You'll have to come up with a way to send commands from the main CPU to the graphics CPU and make sure the graphics CPU doesn't miss any bytes.
- Use an FPGA and make your own GPU in the FPGA.

  FPGAs are **cool**! You can basically build your own IC in software. It's not as fast or cheap as a real IC, but it's still fast enough for a homemade game system GPU. Maybe you can even design a CPU on the same chip (not recommended, though, if you want to be able to compile code for it).

  If you are interested in getting into FPGA programming, I recommend Digilent's Arduino-style "Arty" board, which costs about US $130. Digilent also sell adapters you can use to connect it to speakers and a VGA monitor. *

  You'll still need a way to send commands from the main CPU to the graphics FPGA, but it will simpler since your FPGA code will have a specific circuit for receiving commands - maybe even with SPI or I2C.

As for what *kind* of graphics you'll get, this is up to you, since you'll be designing your own GPU in any case. You could go for tilemaps like the Gameboy, or 3D graphics.

Since it sounds like you're making a handheld system, I guess you don't want a VGA output, but you can output to whatever LCD panel you end up using. VGA might be useful for development.

- **Edit:** There are modules available with built-in graphics processors (e.g. SSD3306 OLED modules, or the modules from 4D Systems*), **however** they are usually aimed towards user interfaces, rather than games. They might not have the features you want (with the SSD3306 you'll probably end up streaming raw pixel data rather than using its built-in features) and they may not be the best value for money. If you find one that matches your requirements, though, you can definitely use it! (I haven't used the ones from 4D Systems but I'm aware they exist, and there are also other manufacturers. Search for display modules with integrated controllers.)

  (Further edit: The asker found the [EV810](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/509338/ft810-eve-as-a-gpu-for-an-embedded-system) and mentioned it in a different question. As I said, it's optimized for user interfaces, but it also looks good enough for a 2D game system, so why not? Good find.)

* while shopping *questions* are off-topic here, I believe it's okay to point to specific products as supplementary information in answers.

Comment: It's not even uncommon with multicore MCUs nowadays. One can design the OS so that it outsources graphics to a specific core. Or not re-invent the wheel but use a desktop OS like Linux/Android.

Comment: @Lundin well, if you use Linux or Android you still need a GPU to run the graphics if you want graphics that require a GPU. And then you may have to write a driver. I doubt Linux has an EV810 driver.

Comment: You could just pick up some cheap Rasp PI with everything pre-made... or you could re-invent the wheel - square shaped this time.

Comment: @Lundin Yes. Raspberry Pi game consoles are a fun project idea. So are non-Raspberry-Pi game consoles.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for all those useful information!